# Spring XD - Event delivery guarantees

Tags: spring-xd

When I create a stream composed of multiple modules, are there any guarantees provided on the event delivery to each module. Is there a possibility of events being replayed?

What if the processor module takes a long time to process one event but crashes in the middle of the processing. What happens to that event when the module is restarted in a container?

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation re: Message Bus Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/#messagebus) and specifically `Error Handling (Message Delivery Failures)`.

The retry configuration can be modified at the bus or individual module/stream level.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I did refer to that document. But I was not sure what happens in the following two scenarios.

i. No Error case: Are the events always delivered only once or is there a possibility of it being delivered more than once?

ii. Module crashes: When the event is dequeued from the Message Bus but the process crashes after dequeuing and while processing. In this case, is the event lost?

Comment: Assuming the rabbit transport; i. There's a small (but non-zero) possibility of a redelivery - if the network goes down after the delivery but before the ack is sent to the broker. The message will be requeued and will be redelivered; you can detect redeliveries using message headers, but you need logic to detect whether the redelivery was successfully processed previously. If using direct binding, the behavior is different in that the exception will be thrown to the previous module. ii. No, again assuming rabbit, the message will be requeued because it was not acknowledged.